# Kerberos defaulting to wrong principal when accessing hdfs from remote server

Tags: hadoop, kerberos

I've configured `kerberos` to access `hdfs` from a remote server and I am able to authenticate and generate a ticket but when I try to access `hdfs` I am getting an error:

> 09/02 15:50:02 WARN ipc.Client: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Server has invalid Kerberos principal: nn/hdp.stack.com@GLOBAL.STACK.COM

in our `krb5.conf` file, we defined the the `admin_server` and `kdc` under a different realm:

```
DEV.STACK.COM = {
admin_server = hdp.stack.com
kdc = hdp.stack.com
}
```

Why is it defaulting to a different realm that is also defined in our `krb5` (GLOBAL.STACK.COM?). I have ensured that all our hadoop xml files are @DEV.STACK.COM

Any ideas? Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

In your KRB5 conf, you should define *explicitly* which machine belongs to which realm, starting with generic rules then adding exceptions.

E.g.

```
[domain_realm]
 stack.com = GLOBAL.STACK.COM
 stack.dev = DEV.STACK.COM

 vm123456.dc01.stack.com = DEV.STACK.COM
 srv99999.dc99.stack.com = DEV.STACK.COM
```

Answer (score 1):

We have a Cluster Spark that requires connect to hdfs on Cloudera and we have getting the same error.

8/08/07 15:04:45 WARN Client: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Server has invalid Kerberos principal: hdfs/host1@REALM.DEV
java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Server has invalid Kerberos principal: hdfs/host1@REALM.DEV; Host Details : local host is: "workstation1.local/10.1.0.62"; destination host is: "host1":8020;

Based on above post of ohshazbot and other post on Cloudera site https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/Kerberos-issue/td-p/29843 we modified the core-site.xml (in Spark Cluster ....spark/conf/core-site.xml)file adding the property and the connection is succesfull

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.kerberos.principal.pattern</name>
  <value>*</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently bumped into an issue with this using HDP2.2 on 2 seperate clusters and after hooking up a debugger to the client I found the issue, which may affect other flavors of hadoop.

There is a possible hdfs config dfs.namenode.kerberos.principal.pattern which dictates if a principal pattern is valid. If the principal doesn't match AND doesn't match the current clusters principal then you get the exception you saw. In hdp2.3 and higher, as well as cdh 5.4 and higher, it looks like this is set to a default of *, which means everything hits. But in HDP2.2 it's not in the defaults so this error occurs whenever you try to talk to the remote kerberized hdfs from your existing kerberized hdfs.

Simply adding this property with *, or any other pattern which matches both local and remote principal names, resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

give  ->

> ls -lart

check for keytab file  ex: .example.keytab

if keytab file is there
give -

> klist -kt keytabfilename

ex: klist -kt .example.keytab

you'll get principal like example@EXAM-PLE.COM in output
then give

> kinit -kt .example.keytab(keytabfile) example@EXAM-PLE.COM(principal)